# Fetching, processing, and storing Mixpanel analytics data to SQLite

Tags: python, json, sqlite, pandas

I'm a self-taught Python programmer and I never really learned the fundamentals of programming, so I want to see how to improve upon this script and make it adhere to best practices.

The script has three functions that retrieve data from an API, cleanse the data and store it in a sqlite db.  This script is going to run daily on a cron and append to the sqlite tables every morning.

1. `get_data()` fetches the data and turns it into a pandas dataframe.
2. `data_cleanse()` removes some non-necessary data.
3. `send_to_db()` sends the cleansed data to a sqlite db, there is one table for each of the event types.

All of the functions are called in a `for`-loop which iterates through each of the event types.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to improve this, but here are some thoughts/questions that I have:

1. Should this be a class?  I have never used one before because I always found plain functions to be less confusing.
2. Should I be using a `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from datetime import date, timedelta
from mixpanel_client_lib import Mixpanel
import sqlite3 as db


def get_data(start_date, end_date, event_name):
    con_data = Mixpanel(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

    data = con_data.request(['export'], {
        'event': [event_name],
        'from_date': start_date,
        'to_date': end_date
    })

    parameters = set()

    events = []

    for line in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            event = json.loads(line)
            ev = event['properties']
        except ValueError:
            continue

        parameters.update(ev.keys())
        events.append(ev)

    df = pd.DataFrame(events)



    return df, event_name


def data_cleanse(df, event_name):
    if event_name == "Video Played":
        df = df[['$ios_ifa',
                 'Groups',
                 'Lifetime Number of Sessions',
                 'Days Since Last Visit',
                 'time',
                 'Product ID',
                 'Time Watched',
                 'Video Length']]

        df.columns = ['ios_id',
                      'groups',
                      'lifetime_sessions',
                      'days_since',
                      'time',
                      'product_id',
                      'time_watched',
                      'video_length']

        print df['lifetime_sessions'].value_counts()

        df['groups'] = df['groups'].astype(str)

        # remove admin users from data
        idx = df['groups'].isin(['[u\'Admin-Personal\']', '[u\'Admin\']'])
        df = df[~idx]

        # remove '0' lifetime session users from data
        idx = df['lifetime_sessions'].isin([0])
        df = df[~idx]

        return df, event_name

    elif event_name == "Item Information Click" or 'Faved' or 'Add to Cart' or 'Tap to Replay':

        print df.columns.values


        df = df[['$ios_ifa',
                 'Groups',
                 'Lifetime Number of Sessions',
                 'Days Since Last Visit',
                 'time',
                 'Product ID']]

        df.columns = ['ios_id',
                      'groups',
                      'lifetime_sessions',
                      'days_since',
                      'time',
                      'product_id']

        df['groups'] = df['groups'].astype(str)

        # remove admin users from data
        idx = df['groups'].isin(['[u\'Admin-Personal\']', '[u\'Admin\']'])
        df = df[~idx]

        # remove '0' lifetime session users from data
        idx = df['lifetime_sessions'].isin([0])
        df = df[~idx]

        return df, event_name


def send_to_db(df, event_name):


    table_names = {
        'Video Played': 'video_played',
        'Item Information Click': 'item_info_click',
        'Faved': 'faved',
        'Add to Cart': 'add_to_cart',
        'Tap to Replay': 'replay'
    }


    con = db.connect('/code/vid_score/test.db')
    df.to_sql(table_names.get(event_name), con, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='append')
    con.close()


################

API_KEY = 'xxxxxxx'
API_SECRET = 'xxxxxxx'

event_types = ['Video Played',
               'Item Information Click',
               'Faved',
               'Add to Cart',
               'Tap to Replay']


end_date = date.today() - timedelta(1)
start_date = date.today() - timedelta(1)

for event in event_types:
    df, event_name = get_data(start_date, end_date, event)
    df, event_name = data_cleanse(df, event_name)
    send_to_db(df, event_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a first look the code is nice enough, meaning you can follow the
control flow easily and it's clear what each function does, so
the separation of the three or four steps is rather good.

1. This script is rather small and you don't pass around too much data;
   I'd say leave it as is unless you want to have some more reuse in
   other scripts.
2. Yes please, do use `__name__` if only for consistency.

I'd also suggest the following to clean up anyway:

- Move constants to the top.
- Use the values from `table_names` instead of `event_types` so you
  don't repeat the keys all the time, so you end up with a constant
  `EVENT_TYPES = {'Video Played': ...}`.
- That way you can also iterate over the event types and table names
  simultaneously, eliminating the need to look up table names in
  `send_to_db`.
- I'd use `timedelta` with named arguments, so it's a bit clearer what
  `timedelta(1)` means, i.e. use `timedelta(days=1)` instead.
- The additional return value for `event_name` from `get_data` and
  `data_cleanse` doesn't make much sense to me.  It's not like you
  transform the event name, so I'd just drop that altogether.
- The spurious `print` statements could be replaced by `logging` calls
  instead, but this looks just like debugging statements anyway?
- The exception handling in `get_data` could be clearer; I've moved the
  access via `'properties'` after the `try` block to make it clearer
  which operation can actually fail there.
- Database connections should probably be protected by
  `with closing(...)` just in case.
- `parameters` in `get_data` is unused.
- The cases in `data_cleanse` are duplicated and can be condensed.
- The comparison `foo == 'x' or 'y'` doesn't do what you mean.  Compare
  `'a' == 'x' or 'y'`, which is `'y'`, with `'a' == 'x' or 'a' == 'y'`,
  which returns `False`.  In any case, this comparison can be rewritten
  with `x in (...)` instead.  You also miss the (currently impossible)
  `else` case; depending on your code I'd rather just have the default
  case and handle `"Video Played"` additionally or raise an exception
  yourself.
- The line after `# remove admin users from data` looks fishy, but I
  don't really know how to improve it.

And finally you can always check with [`flake8`](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/) and similar tools for
style violations.
All in all:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from datetime import date, timedelta
from mixpanel_client_lib import Mixpanel
import sqlite3 as db
from contextlib import closing


API_KEY = 'xxxxxxx'
API_SECRET = 'xxxxxxx'

EVENT_TYPES = {
    'Video Played': 'video_played',
    'Item Information Click': 'item_info_click',
    'Faved': 'faved',
    'Add to Cart': 'add_to_cart',
    'Tap to Replay': 'replay'
}

DEFAULT_COLUMNS = [
    ('$ios_ifa', 'ios_id'),
    ('Groups', 'groups'),
    ('Lifetime Number of Sessions', 'lifetime_sessions'),
    ('Days Since Last Visit', 'days_since'),
    ('time', 'time'),
    ('Product ID', 'product_id'),
]

VIDEO_COLUMNS = list(DEFAULT_COLUMNS).extend([
    ('Time Watched', 'time_watched'),
    ('Video Length', 'video_length')
])


def get_data(start_date, end_date, event_name):
    con_data = Mixpanel(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

    data = con_data.request(['export'], {
        'event': [event_name],
        'from_date': start_date,
        'to_date': end_date
    })

    events = []

    for line in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            event = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        events.append(event['properties'])

    return pd.DataFrame(events)


def data_cleanse(df, event_name):
    columns = DEFAULT_COLUMNS
    if event_name == "Video Played":
        columns = VIDEO_COLUMNS

    df = df[[c[0] for c in columns]]
    df.columns = [c[1] for c in columns]

    df['groups'] = df['groups'].astype(str)

    # remove admin users from data
    idx = df['groups'].isin(['[u\'Admin-Personal\']', '[u\'Admin\']'])
    df = df[~idx]

    # remove '0' lifetime session users from data
    idx = df['lifetime_sessions'].isin([0])
    df = df[~idx]

    return df


def send_to_db(df, table_name):
    with closing(db.connect('/code/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df.to_sql(table_name, con, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='append')


def main():
    end_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    start_date = end_date

    for (event_name, table_name) in EVENT_TYPES.iteritems():
        df = get_data(start_date, end_date, event_name)
        df = data_cleanse(df, event_name)
        send_to_db(df, table_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing.  I have some research to do on your notes/changes.